# Difference between Instance State and Volume State

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

What is difference between Instance State and Volume States ?At one place for EBS instance I got Instance State as available/in-use and in some documentary read Volume state as OK/Warning/impaired/insufficient Data.

I had gone through this Link for volume state:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-volume-status.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instances and volumes are different things. Instances are [defined by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts.html) as virtual computing environments. You can think of them as virtual machines. Volumes on the other hand are used for storage, similar to a (virtual) hard drive.

Furthermore, there is no such thing as an *EBS Instance*. There are only EBS volumes.

That said, you are completely right that EBS Volumes have two kinds of states/status.
The first one is one of `(creating | available | in-use | deleting | deleted | error)`. When you select a volume in the AWS management console, it is shown in the description tab:
[image]
The second kind of status is one of `(OK | Warning | impaired | insufficient data)` and results from the status checks that are performed periodically and described at the documentation site you have mentioned. It is shown in the Status Checks tab:
[image]

To sum up, these are two different kinds of status information. The first one gives more general information about the volume. The second one is determined via status checks and gives information about the health of the volume.

Comment: Thanks got it,I was confused between state and status.